# How to use tls package with React Native

Tags: ssl, openssl, react-native

I've managed to shim the `net` package using `rn-nodeify`, however it doesn't seem to have any support for the `tls` package.

I don't see any reason why React Native wouldn't be capable of supporting OpenSSL, so I'm unsure if I've just not been able to find a solution, or if there's nothing available as of yet?

Comment: I don't have a solution for SSL/TSL (still looking myself), but for "net" you may want to consider [this native package for react-native](https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp), which is actively maintained too it seems (last commit 19 days ago right now). Unfortunately [they don't seem to have plans to support encrypted connections](https://github.com/PeelTechnologies/react-native-tcp/issues/15).

Comment: Thanks @MörreNoseshine. I believe that's actually the same underlying package that `rn-nodeify` uses to shim the library. It seems to work quite well, although I did have some issues with Android initially.

Comment: @Adam I have the same problem. Can you solved this?? 'tls' not found.  
 :-(

Comment: @KishanVaghela unfortunately not. I was only building a prototype at the time, so I gave up trying to get it to work. That was about 9 months ago though, so things may have changed since then. If you manage to find a solution it would be great to hear about :)